# Get the Debian partition tool on console

Tags: linux, partitioning

While installing Debian, there was this ultra cool, easy to use partition tool. One can set up LVMs, encrypted disks, encrypted LVMs and whatnot.

Can I get this tool back, without putting in a installation disk? Or is there a similar tool, that works on console?

The graphics don't have to be pretty, they weren't while installing, but a bit more comfort than hacking away on console would be nice.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/amd64/apcs05.html.en I think it might be `cfdisk`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the Debian installer uses `partman`. You could also use `fdisk`(command-line) or `cfdisk`(console gui).