# Partman doesn't allow set mount point to a LVM on Debian installation

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, lvm

While installing Debian the partman doesn't allow set an LVM as root file system, cant set / as mountpoint to a LVM filesystem, but when choose "use entire disk and setup LVM" partman comes with a recipe very next to what i want, just make a small /boot partition and I need one bigger because already had system crash with this default setup because of it.

There is a [question](https://superuser.com/q/1115140/939577) where people tell it need to be with another tool and is impossible do it with partman but doesn't tell how to switch tool, I believe it is choosing text mode installation and I will try.

Would be nice if there is a way to change the scheme done by partman at any point, change size, mountpoint, label, names, etc.

The recipe  "use entire disk and setup LVM" from partman generate it:

[image: use entire disk and setup LVM by partman]

I just need it but with bigger /boot

There is this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/858031/895737) asking how to expand boot partition in front of LVM and @solsTiCe told to move the boot partition at the end of the drive allowing increase size, with "use entire disk and setup LVM" recipe I can do it but then I will end with boot at end of drive but its so jerry-rigged to do on a fresh install.

There is [this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=516347) page describing it is done with a custom preseed recipe but looks like an overkill and I dont know how to do preseeding partionning recipes load on Debian install.

Answer (score 0):

You can move to Ubuntu that comes with 1G boot recipe on partman, just remember to increase the % size of main partition as you can see done here:
[Ubuntu with partman recipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlHCU.png)

You can also, if have huge memory, remove swap as you can see [here](https://serverfault.com/a/969584/514993).